# How do i fix an import issue with the OculusVR SDK?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error, virtual-reality, oculus

error: error CS0117: 'FeatureHelpers' does not contain a definition for 'GetFeatureWithIdForBuildTarget'

so I downloaded the oculus SDK package for unity and I get an does not contain definition. i looked into the class that it should be in and as far as i see it is in there. so why the error. anyone with experience that can tell me a solution to this?

variable that is not defined:

```
var oculusXRFeature = FeatureHelpers.GetFeatureWithIdForBuildTarget(report.summary.platformGroup, Oculus.XR.OculusXRFeature.featureId);
```

Class:

```
public static class FeatureHelpers
    {
public static OpenXRFeature[] GetFeaturesWithIdsForActiveBuildTarget(string[] featureIds);
        public static OpenXRFeature GetFeatureWithIdForActiveBuildTarget(string featureId); // the defined variable
        public static void RefreshFeatures(BuildTargetGroup group);
    }
```

I expected to download a library to use the OVR SDK. and now it randomly has an SDK error

Comment: GetFeaturesWithIdsForActiveBuildTarget isn't the same as GetFeatureWithIdForBuildTarget. It's not clear what you mean by "i looked into the class that it should be in and as far as i see it is in there"

Comment: i now specified the line that I meant with comments behind it in the class but on the second public static OpenXRFeature is the var defined and that is why I don't know why it gives me this error.

Comment: What do you mean by "the defined variable"? That's a method, not a variable. But still, the name you're trying to use in the code (`GetFeatureWithIdForBuildTarget`) isn't the same as the name declared (`GetFeatureWithIdForActiveBuildTarget`) - the *actual* declaration contains the word "Active".

Comment: oh i see what you mean. well then in this whole library it isn't defined like the code says. I'll try to look into the documentation to see if i can maybe get that line of code hope it works then